# bash: ./soundboard.sh: /bin/sh^M: Bad Interpreter: No such file or directory 1

Tags: bash

I want to run this Script on my pi but it returns allways the same Message:

bash: ./soundboard.sh: /bin/sh^M: Bad Interpreter: No such file or directory 1
How can I fix this? Thanks for help

```
#!/bin/sh
USER="pi"
SERVER_PORT=8080
SERVICE_NAME=Soundboard
PATH_TO_JAR=/home/pi/DiscordBot
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/soundboard-pid
case $1 in
    start)
    echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
    if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
        cd $PATH_TO_JAR
        sudo -u $USER nohup java -Dserver.port=$SERVER_PORT -jar $PATH_TO_JAR/DiscordSoundboard.jar /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
            echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
    else
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
    fi
;;
stop)
    if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
        PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
        kill $PID;
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
        rm $PID_PATH_NAME
    else
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
    fi
;;
restart)
    if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
        PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
        kill $PID;
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
        rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
        cd $PATH_TO_JAR
        sudo -u $USER nohup java -Dserver.port=$SERVER_PORT -jar $PATH_TO_JAR/DiscordSoundboard.jar /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
            echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
    else
        echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
    fi
;;
esac
```

Comment: Try changing 1st line to #!/bin/bash